# hadoop 2.7.3 not able to start namenode on cygwin(windows 10)

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have installed `Cygwin`  on Windows. Then I installed `Hadoop 2.7.3` on it and followed all the instructions given in [this post](http://hadooponwindows.blogspot.in/2016/09/installing-apache-hadoop-on-windows-10.html).

After completion of the installation, it is running resource manager successfully on `localhost:8088` but not running `namenode` on `localhost:50070`.

After giving `jps` command it is showing output as:

```
3192 ResourceManager
4636 Jps
(namenode related information is not showing in output of jps).
```

Comment: Please check the namenode logs for more details.

Comment: I doubt you didn't format namenode.

Comment: Update your post with namenode logs